# geom_histogram does not show all values in x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying to run a simple and quick analysis of some variables. I run this code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(var1)) +
    geom_bar()
```

Resulting in a Histogram however in spite of having only 6 possible values in var1, x Axis only shows 2,4,6. Is it possible to easily include all 6 possible values as labels?

Comment: This question will be downvoted or closed if you don't supply a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, are you sure you want a histogram, and not a bar plot? (`geom_bar`)? Take a look at [this page](https://keydifferences.com/difference-between-histogram-and-bar-graph.html).

Comment: I'm using geom_bar() resulting plot is a plot with frequency of values, however x axis is missing some values in the axis

Comment: OK, so turn your x into a factor, then it should work as intended. `aes(factor(var1))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have frequency bar plot for six individual numbers. However, you wish to see all of these numbers on the X axis, which makes me think that you actually treat them as categorical data rather then numeric data, so you actually would prefer a categorical X axis which shows all the data. Turning the x into a factor should do the trick:

```
data <- data.frame(var1=floor(6*runif(200)  + 1))
ggplot(data, aes(factor(var1))) + geom_bar()
```

Below: left - without `factor`, right - with `factor`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What does your data look like?

Assuming you have a numeric x, adding `scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,6, by = 1))`should work.

Of course this would only work if the x values go from 1 to 6... Otherwise you can replace the seq call with a vector that contains the values you want.

Comment: How do you know the other 3 values are not 8, 10 and 12?

Comment: variable values goes from 1 to 6. Did a count to verify